# SICStus Prolog making product/3 rule from sum/3

Tags: prolog

First of all, this is a homework question, so please just give me a hint!

```
%Here is a rule that defines sum/3 that returns yes if Z is sum of X and Y
sum(X,Y,Z) :-
  Z is X + Y.
%How can I make product/3
product(X,Y,Z) :- % based on sum/3 above?
```

Also, how can write a query on product such that it returns the answer of X * Y and not that it's merely true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that in mathematics:

```
x * 0 = 0
x * y = x + x * (y - 1)
```

That should help you write your rules.

As for a query, you can use something like this to get a result like this:

```
?- product(5, 3, Result).
Result = 15 ?
yes
```

In short, if you have an unbound variable in a query, it tries to find a value for that variable such that the predicate succeeds.

Comment: hey I have a question about successor functor. It isn't a predefined function in SICStus right? How do you define s(X) in prolog?

Comment: @HwaSooCho: I'm sorry; I have no experience with SICStus in particular; just Prolog in general. You'd probably have better luck starting a new question.